# How do I make an invalid attributes test pass with zero allowed or required attributes

Tags: elixir, ecto, ex-unit

Using Ecto 2.0 I'm trying to make this test pass:

```
defmodule PlexServer.FleetInstanceTest do
  use PlexServer.ModelCase

  alias PlexServer.FleetInstance

  @invalid_attrs %{some_random_data: "random data"}

  test "changeset with invalid attributes" do
    changeset = FleetInstance.changeset(%FleetInstance{}, @invalid_attrs)
    refute changeset.valid?
  end
end
```

Here's the model

```
defmodule PlexServer.FleetInstance do
  use PlexServer.Web, :model

  schema "fleet_instances" do
    has_many :ship_instance, PlexServer.ShipInstance

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
    model
      |> cast(params, [])
      |> validate_required([])
  end
end
```

It seems cast simply ignores any data that is not in the allowed list so the changeset is considered valid, failing the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Ecto.Changeset.cast/3` will ignore any fields not specified in the third argument, and as you are passing `[]` to `validate_required`, there's really no possible `params` that would make your current version of `PlexServer.FleetInstance.changeset/2` return `valid?: false`.

Comment: In this case is it common to simply get rid of the test? And perhaps bring it back if the schema changes?

Comment: @AlejandroHuerta Yes. Your function is valid for any attributes, so testing invalid attributes doesn't make sense for now.

Comment: @tkowal, makes sense. Thanks